# How can I replace all day values in a date with a specific value?

Tags: r, date

I have the following vector of dates in the format of m/d/y:

```
(dates<-c("1/31/2018", "2/31/2018", "3/0/2018", "4/31/2018", "9/5/2018"))
[1] "1/31/2018" "2/31/2018" "3/0/2018" "1/5/2018"
```

If you look carefully, some of these dates are nonsensical -e.g. there aren't 31 days in February and 0 is not a valid day of the month. I would like the replace all the day values with "1". I'd like my result to look like the following:

```
dates
[1] "1/1/2018" "2/1/2018" "3/1/2018" "4/1/2018" "9/1/2018"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert the bad ones only first attempt to convert to `Date` class and if that gives NA replace the middle portion.

```
ifelse(is.na(as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%Y")), sub("/.*/", "/1/", dates), dates)
## [1] "1/31/2018" "2/1/2018"  "3/1/2018"  "4/1/2018"  "9/5/2018"
```

or to convert all of them:

```
sub("/.*/", "/1/", dates)
## [1] "1/1/2018" "2/1/2018" "3/1/2018" "4/1/2018" "9/1/2018"
```

Here is a second way to convert all of them:

```
with(read.table(text = dates, sep = "/"), paste(V1, 1, V3, sep = "/"))
## [1] "1/1/2018" "2/1/2018" "3/1/2018" "4/1/2018" "9/1/2018"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the basic idea from @G. Grothendieck in combination with `lubridate`:

```
ifelse(is.na(mdy(dates)), sub("/.*/", "/1/", dates), dates)

[1] "1/31/2018" "2/1/2018"  "3/1/2018"  "4/1/2018"  "9/5/2018"
```

Or replacing `sub()` with `strsplit()`:

```
day <- unlist(sapply(strsplit(dates, "/"), head, 1))
year <- unlist(sapply(strsplit(dates, "/"), tail, 1))

ifelse(is.na(mdy(dates)), paste(day, "1", year, sep = "/"), dates)
```